# Can anyone get any data back for UK from Alpha Vantage?

Tags: rest, alpha-vantage

Can anyone get data back from London using the Alpha Vantage API?

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=LON:SSE.L&apikey=mykeyhere
```

The endpoint returns information for US listed companies, but when you try to switch to UK or anywhere else you get {}.

I've tried encoding the dot as `%2e` and adding a `" - "` as described by a user here but still nothing. I've also tried  changing the exchange code between XLON and LON. This had no effect.

Has anybody had a similar experience or have a working call?

Comment: **Note for March 2021**  At the minute something is going on. Last week, most European tickers, including LSE, were returning empty objects (when formatted correctly with dot suffix. Now LSE (`.L`) and DAX (`.DE`) work, but not Swiss (`.SW`) or Milan (`.MI`) are still broken. They used to work with both the old way and new way. https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=FCA.MI&apikey=. The Swiss in particular works only for `function=GLOBAL_QUOTE` not for timeseries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of today the query you have written above works for me with a free API key. It produces a JSON object with the key "Global Quote", containing another object with 10 entries ("01. symbol", "02. open", "03. high", "04. low", "05. price", "06. volume", "07. latest trading day", "08. previous close", "09. change" and "10. change percent").